# Dual boot problems 16.04

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I'm new using Ubuntu, I download Ubuntu in dual boot, I made the partition as you said in the forum. I download Ubuntu 16.04 in my flashdrive and when I wanted to restart the laptop it restarted in Windows. I changed disabled the secure boot and enable legacy, this allow me to boot in the partition destinated to Ubuntu. In the Ubuntu desktop, you have two disks: one you find windows files and in the other one 31 GB I supposed is the Ubuntu partition. I really would like have the dual boot, please what can I do. I tried also to:

```
sudo update-grub:
##/usr/sbin/grub-probe:error:failed to get canonical path of /cow.
```

I don't know what to do? I need an orientation please.

As you ask me, I supposed that is my summary report, so long, sorry, I tried to resume, I erase some parts:

> > > sudo apt-add-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair
> > >       Simple tool to repair frequent boot problems.

Website: https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home
Press [ENTER]...

gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmp9xslvw7f/secring.gpg' created

gpg: keyring`/tmp/tmp9xslvw7f/pubring.gpg' created
gpg:               imported: 1  (RSA: 1)
OK
Ign:1 cdrom://Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS *Xenial Xerus* - Release amd64 (20160719) xenial InRelease
Hit:2 cdrom://Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS *Xenial Xerus* - Release amd64 (20160719) xenial Release
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
The following additional packages will be installed:
  boot-sav boot-sav-extra gawk glade2script libsigsegv2 pastebinit python-gi
Suggested packages:
  mbr mdadm clean-ubiquity boot-info os-uninstaller gawk-doc python-gi-cairo
Recommended packages:
  gksu
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  boot-repair boot-sav boot-sav-extra gawk glade2script libsigsegv2 pastebinit python-gi
0 upgraded, 8 newly installed, 0 to remove and 349 not upgraded.
Need to get 1,228 kB of archives.
After this operation, 5,139 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 libsigsegv2 amd64 2.10-4 [14.1 kB]
Selecting previously unselected package libsigsegv2:amd64.
(Reading database ... 191931 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libsigsegv2_2.10-4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libsigsegv2:amd64 (2.10-4) ...
Setting up libsigsegv2:amd64 (2.10-4) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package gawk.
(Reading database ... 191939 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../gawk_1%3a4.1.3+dfsg-0.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gawk (1:4.1.3+dfsg-0.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python-gi.
Preparing to unpack .../python-gi_3.20.0-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking python-gi (3.20.0-0ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package glade2script.
Preparing to unpack .../glade2script_3.2.3~ppa1_all.deb ...
Unpacking glade2script (3.2.3~ppa1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package boot-sav.
Preparing to unpack .../boot-sav_4ppa40_all.deb ...
Unpacking boot-sav (4ppa40) ...
Selecting previously unselected package boot-repair.
Preparing to unpack .../boot-repair_4ppa40_all.deb ...
Unpacking boot-repair (4ppa40) ...
Selecting previously unselected package boot-sav-extra.
Preparing to unpack .../boot-sav-extra_4ppa40_all.deb ...
Unpacking boot-sav-extra (4ppa40) ...
Selecting previously unselected package pastebinit.
Preparing to unpack .../pastebinit_1.5-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking pastebinit (1.5-1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu3.1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu5) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.3~bzr0+16.04.20160701-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.59ubuntu1) ...
Setting up gawk (1:4.1.3+dfsg-0.1) ...
Setting up python-gi (3.20.0-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up glade2script (3.2.3~ppa1) ...
Setting up boot-sav (4ppa40) ...
Setting up boot-repair (4ppa40) ...
Setting up boot-sav-extra (4ppa40) ...
Setting up pastebinit (1.5-1) ...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help you:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair
```

Comment: Post link from the Summary Report that Boot-Repair creates. Are both Windows & Ubuntu installed in same boot mode, either both UEFI or both BIOS/Legacy/CSM?

Comment: Than you Tadeu, i tried **sudo apt-add-repository, and I have handling with many file under: During handling of the above exception, another exception ocurred.                                                                                                                                         And at the end:  ERROR: '~yannubutu' user or team does not exist.
Error: 'ppa:yannubutu/boot-repair' invalid
I will try the other one!

Comment: I add the answers that I have with the commands, I donwload a package isn't to correct errors? Now how can I know which one is the problem, sorry but I don't understand all the codes is like advanced chinese for me. Thank you!!!

Comment: Lara Key! Did  you already fix the error?